# Verify table Row's data attribute with keys in a dictionary

Tags: javascript, html

What I'm trying to do here, is, for every row in the table, I want to verify the row's data attribute (Note that the data attribute of this row is the socket One of the keys in the clientel dictionary previously made) with the keys in the dictionary clientel. If both match, do nothing. If the key is in the row but not in the dictionary, perform a function and if there's a key in the dictionary but it's not in a row, then add that row.

```
let clientel = {
    socket101: ['Rick', '192.590.49.1', 'Win10', 'Norway', '15:49.00'],
    socket102: ['Anthony', '192.90.897.0', 'Win7', 'Negritine', '19:19:38']
};

function man_table() {
    const table = document.getElementById('table-body');
    for(let i in clientel) {
        for(let ih = 0, row; row = table.rows[ih]; ih++) {
            ass = row.getAttribute('data');
            if (ass in clientel) {}
            else if (!(ass in clientel)) {table.deleteRow(ih); continue;}
            else if (clientel[i] !== ass) {
                let row = table.insertRow(i);
                let client = clientel[i];
                row.setAttribute('data', i);
                let name = row.insertCell(0);
                let ip = row.insertCell(1);
                let os = row.insertCell(2);
                let country = row.insertCell(3);
                let timee = row.insertCell(4);

                name.innerHTML = client[0];
                ip.innerHTML = client[1];
                os.innerHTML = client[2];
                country.innerHTML = client[3];
                timee.innerHTML = client[4];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this add the tables and
Is there a better way to do this?

Example of the HTML table (On Request):

```
<div id="table">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>IP</th>
                        <th>OS</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                        <th>Connected Since</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="table-body">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rick</td>
                        <td>192.423.41.5</td>
                        <td>Win 7</td>
                        <td>Bulgaria</td>
                        <td>A few moments</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Issue is your flow of control.  It's equivalent to `if ( something) {} else if (not something) { delete row } else /* never gets called because the first two if statements eat all cases */`

Comment: So how do I go about fixing this? The only thing I can think of is making a separate functions for the last else statement and calling that function at the end of the original `man_table()` function (after the if statement has executed) but then I'll run into another problem. I know that this code is really stupid. It'll keep on adding a table and removing it. Is there a way to verify the data attributes of all the rows in that table at once?

Comment: Add an example of your table (HTML) to the question.

Comment: Done. Added the HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try and do too many things at the same time.  Adding rows in the same loop where you're deleting rows is going to cause confusion.

Notice that your HTML does not actually have the `data` attributes on the `TR` elements, so your code will never match any rows.  Also, trying to this: `let row = table.insertRow(i);` will fail because `i` is a string (`"socket101"` etc)

The delete first looks for rows that don't have a corresponding entry in the `clientel` dictionary.  `[...table.rows]` converts the HTMLCollection into an array so that `filter` can be used, which simply returns the entry from the dictionary matching it's `data` attribute.  This will be `null` for any row that doesn't have an entry.

Once we have a list of rows that don't have matching clients remove the rows.  Find the index of the row by deconstructing the row ( `.forEach({rowIndex}) => foo(rowIndex)` has the same effect as `.forEach(row) => foo(row.rowIndex)` ), and then delete the row (remembering to account for the table header row).

Adding the new row is about the same as the delete.  The `.map( (key, index) ) => [ key, index ] )` is used to preserve the index of each client so the row can be added in the correct place later.  The filter is similar as the delete but instead of including things that exist, it includes anything that doesn't exist.  This depends on `null` being effectively the same as `false` (i.e `!null` evaluates as `true`).  Adding rows is done by using HTML, which is faster than creating elements/nodes individually.

```js
let clientel = {
    socket101: ['Rick', '192.590.49.1', 'Win10', 'Norway', '15:49.00'],
    socket102: ['Anthony', '192.90.897.0', 'Win7', 'Negritine', '19:19:38']
};

function init() {
    const table = document.getElementById('table-body');

    // remove anything that doesn't have a row in the clientel map
    [...table.rows].filter( (row) => !clientel[row.getAttribute('data')] )
                   .forEach( ({rowIndex}) => table.deleteRow(rowIndex - 1) )

    // add anything that doesn't exist in the table
    Object.keys(clientel)
          .map( (key, index) => [ key, index ] )
          .filter( ([key, index]) => !table.querySelector(`tr[data="${key}"]`) )
          .forEach( ([key, index]) => {
              var row = table.insertRow(index)
              row.setAttribute('data', key);
              row.innerHTML = clientel[key].map( value => `<td>${value}</td>` ).join("");
          });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
</script>
```

```html
<div id="table">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>IP</th>
                        <th>OS</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                        <th>Connected Since</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="table-body">
                    <tr data="socket101">
                        <td>Rick</td>
                        <td>192.423.41.5</td>
                        <td>Win 7</td>
                        <td>Bulgaria</td>
                        <td>A few moments</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data="socket103">
                        <td>Whoever</td>
                        <td>127.0.0.1</td>
                        <td>OS/1</td>
                        <td>The Moon</td>
                        <td>Whatever</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank You so much! Also, if it's not too much to ask, could you maybe tell me what [...table.rows] is (like why is it in square brackets and the 3 dots in the beginning) and in `.forEach( ({rowIndex})` why is rowIndex in curly brackets, are or maybe tell me what to look for or some source to read from? I'm fairly new to JS and I really want to learn how this works.

Comment: `[ ]` constructs an array. `...` is the [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), which expands all elements of an iterable (like HTMLCollection) in place.  `[...table.rows]` is literally "make an array out of everything in table.rows".  `.forEach( ({rowIndex}) ` is using deconstruction/destructuring.  If you only want a certain property (or set of properties) from an object you can destructure the object and just take what you need.  In the code above all that is needed from a row is the rowIndex.

Comment: If you had an object, `var foo = { key1: "value1", key2: "value2" }` you can do `var {key1} = foo` and the new variable `key1` would be set to "value1"

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late reply. This was very clear and I understood what you taught me up there. Could you tell me what `Object.keys(clientel)` does. Like I'm guessing it's getting the **key** objects from the `clientel` dictionary but tell me if I'm wrong. Also, where'd you get the **key** and **index** variables from? I mean you didn't declare them so how'd you get them? Are they part of the keys Object?

Comment: Yes, [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) just returns the list of keys in an object.  I actually did declare both of them.  When you define an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (`(param) => statement`) the parameters are declared in the same way as they are for any function.  `(key, index) => [ key, index ]` declares an arrow function that takes two parameters, `key` and `index`

Comment: Aah! That's interesting. Thank You.